# Unescape in Java 6

Tags: jsp, escaping, apache-commons, java-6, unescapestring

I have a jsp in which I need to do an unescape fix. I need to show this **\uFFA0\uFFA0\uFF94\uFF93\uFF82\uFFA0** (which are japanese characteres) in a readable format.

I can see that in javascript, it works fine running this in console:
*unescape('\uFFA0\uFFA0\uFF94\uFF93\uFF82\uFFA0')*

Hope to get some help on this. I must to do it in Java 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can output direct the string

```
"&#xFFA0;&#xFFA0;&#xFF94;&#xFF93;&#xFF82;&#xFFA0;"
```

Comment: Hi Holger, is there any way to do it in Java 6?

Comment: In JSP you can output this String. The browser will show it like your unescape().